# SyncDatabaseHelper not found with github.com/ntoskrnl/DataSync

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, synchronization

I am working on a small app in which I want to have an SQLite DB to work locally but have it synced with parse.com.

I am trying to follow the example at https://github.com/ntoskrnl/DataSync but I am having problems with this statement:

```java
// obtain our DatabaseHelper object
SyncDatabaseHelper dbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context,  DatabaseHelper.class);

// create and initialize SyncHelper object
SyncHelper syncHelper = new SyncHelper(dbHelper); 
syncHelper.setUserId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
syncHelper.setLastSyncDate(new Date(lastSyncDate));
```

`SyncDatabaseHelper` does not seem to be a known class.

Comment: `I am having problems`. could you be any less specific?

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough: 
SyncDatabaseHelper doesnt seem to be a know java class and cant find it anywhere after googling for it

Comment: I think it is a typo. The signature from `OpenHelperManager.getHelper` in ORMlite seems to indicate that it should return an instance of `DatabaseHelper`.

Comment: I would suggest you open an issue on the github repo directly to get the attention of the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in the README file. Thank you for mentioning, I updated it.

As **njzk2** pointed out, it is better to open an issue on GitHub.

First of all, the database operations shouldn't be performed on the UI thread. You should do all your work with DB in background thread (such as `AsyncTask` or Bolts task).

Secondly, you there is no need in additional `updatedAt` field in your entity-class. `SyncEntity` that you extend already has the field `syncDate` mapped to the `updatedAt` of `ParseObject`. Also, you cannot directly change `updatedAt` in your ParseObject, so the library uses reflection for this.

Just use `syncDate` instead of `updatedAt`. When you create new category or update existing one, you should set or update `syncDate` field of your entity - just as you did with `updatedAt` in your code.

Here is how I use the library in one of my projects:

```java
ProgressDialog pDialog = null;

public void sync() {
    // show progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    pDialog.setMessage("Synchronizing session data...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    // get last sync date from preferences
    final Date lastSyncDate = new Date(mPrefHelper.getLong(
            Constants.APP_LAST_SYNC_TIMESTAMP, 0L));

    // Prepare SyncHelper
    final SyncHelper syncHelper = new SyncHelper(HelperFactory.getHelper());
    syncHelper.setUserId(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    syncHelper.setLastSyncDate(lastSyncDate);

    Task.callInBackground(
            new Callable<Long>() {

                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    // save sync timestamp
                    long sync = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    syncHelper.synObjects(CardioSessionEntity.class, true, new SyncCallback());
                    return sync;
                }
            }
    ).continueWith(
            new Continuation<Long, Object>() {

                @Override
                public Object then(Task<Long> task) throws Exception {
                    if (task.isFaulted()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Sync failed with exception", task.getError());
                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sync failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (task.isCompleted()) {
                        // save new sync timestamp to Preferences
                        mPrefHelper.putLong(Constants.APP_LAST_SYNC_TIMESTAMP, task.getResult());
                    }

                    // refresh UI and hide progress dialog
                    refreshSessionList();
                    if (pDialog != null) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    pDialog = null;
                    return null;
                }
            },
            Task.UI_THREAD_EXECUTOR);
}
```

I store last sync timestamp in Android preferences and use Bolts task to do synchronization in background. The synchronisation is performed by calling `syncHelper.syncObjects()`. I provide the entity-class, a `userAware` flag and `SyncCallback` object (can be `null`).

In the app, I have `Sync` button. Every time user clicks on it, I call the method `sync()` shown above. For each updated object the corresponding methods of `SyncCallback` are called.

For your particular case, I assume you don't need `userId`, so you can call

```java
// Do this in the background

// save sync timestamp
long sync = System.currentTimeMillis();
// sync Category.class
syncHelper.synObjects(Category.class);
// return sync timestamp to save it in the later
return sync;
```

Call it from within `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` whenever you want to perform synchronization.

The `syncDate` is optional. If you don't provide `lastSyncDate`, the library will request all objects from the server.

Because the library doesn't support (and is not aware of) the relationships between your database entities, if you synchronize multiple entity-classes, you must handle save operations using `SyncCallback`. Its methods `onSaveLocally()` and `onSaveRemotely()` will be invoked just before persist/update (in local DB) or save (to parse.com).

Comment: @user1809819, you should have added your code to the Question post (no need write this as answer). I will edit the question for you, and update my answer.

Comment: @user1809819, if you need more clarifications, please open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ntoskrnl/DataSync/issues